Is there an inconsistency with the usually relation definitions?
If we want to use sets for relations then the domains and ranges must be functions $dom$ and $ran$, but then we have a problem; if a relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$, and $S$ from $C$ to $D$, are equal R = S (for example if $A \subseteq C \text{ and } B \subseteq D$), then we have that dom(R) = dom(S), thus A = dom(R) = dom(S) = C, which is an inconsistency. Where am I going wrong?
Or would we not even consider the situation where we have two relations of distinct domains in this manner? or is this simply a technicality? I know we can define the relations to include the domains if we want, but I am just trying to understand the set-wise definition of relations.

You will have to follow the technical definitions used in that place.  For example,  we could say a relation is a triple $\mathfrak R = \langle R, A, B\rangle$, where $A,B$ are two sets and $R \subseteq A \times B$.  If your text has some other definition, use it.

$\text{dom}(R)$ is not $A$ but $\lbrace x\in A:\exists y\in B(xRy)\rbrace$

Under most definitions when we say $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ we mean $ R \subseteq A$ x $B$.
